# Historical order of introduction of numerical methods for PDE: finite difference, element, volume, and spectral methods.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, math-history

I wanted to ask the community if what I believe is the order of the introduction of these methods are ballpark correct, and the order they were introduced. It would be appreciated if folks could tell me if this is wrong

I think its

finite difference (late 1930s/early 1940s) -> finite-element (1950s)->  finite volume (1960s) -> spectral method (1970s)

Thank you.

Comment: This question is better suited for History of Science and Mathematics (HSM) site.

Comment: Besides, I don't see the coherence between spectral method(s) and the rest. You should be more explicit about the domain you are "targetting".

Comment: Is this article of interest to you : https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jpeterson/history_fem.pdf ?